# Cannot click on interstitial ad in WebView fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview, admob

I have made an AdvanceWebView Application.

In that I have made a function to show interstitialAd in "fragmentActivity", that means whenever I download something from that webview that Ad will show up but it isn't clickable.

I think my ad is showing behind that fragment or something like that or maybe some other issue.
And when Vedio Ads are showen, the countdown of that ad also doesn't woprking.

I can see the Ad but it isn't clickable and if I click on any part of Ad, Logcat
is showing this => "I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null"

Here it is some part of my code:

WebfragmentActivy:

```
public class WebFragment extends Fragment implements AdvancedWebView.Listener, SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener{

        //Layouts
        public FrameLayout rl;
        public AdvancedWebView browser;
        public SwipeRefreshLayout swipeLayout;
        public ProgressBar progressBar;

        //WebView Clients
        public WebToAppChromeClient chromeClient;
        public WebToAppWebClient webClient;

        //WebView Session
        public String mainUrl = null;
        static String URL = "url";
        public int firstLoad = 0;

        //Keep track of the interstitials we show
        private int interstitialCount = -1;

        public WebFragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }



        public static WebFragment newInstance(String url) {
            WebFragment fragment = new WebFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString(URL, url);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public void setBaseUrl(String url){
            this.mainUrl = url;
            browser.loadUrl(mainUrl);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            if (getArguments() != null && mainUrl == null) {
                mainUrl = getArguments().getString(URL);
                firstLoad = 0;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            rl = (FrameLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_observable_web_view, container,
                    false);

            progressBar = (ProgressBar) rl.findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
            browser = (AdvancedWebView) rl.findViewById(R.id.scrollable);
            swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) rl.findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);

            return rl;
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

            if (Config.PULL_TO_REFRESH)
                swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
            else
                swipeLayout.setEnabled(false);

            // Setting the webview listeners
            browser.setListener(this, this);

            // set javascript and zoom and some other settings
            browser.requestFocus();
            browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            browser.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
            browser.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
            browser.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
            browser.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            // Below required for geolocation
            browser.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
            // 3RD party plugins (on older devices)
            browser.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);

            if (Config.MULTI_WINDOWS) {
                browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
                browser.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
            }

            webClient = new WebToAppWebClient(getActivity(), browser);
            browser.setWebViewClient(webClient);

            chromeClient = new WebToAppChromeClient(getActivity(), rl, browser, swipeLayout, progressBar);
            browser.setWebChromeClient(chromeClient);

            // load url (if connection available
            if (webClient.hasConnectivity(mainUrl, true)) {
                String pushurl = ((App) getActivity().getApplication()).getPushUrl();
                if (pushurl != null){
                    browser.loadUrl(pushurl);
                } else {
                    browser.loadUrl(mainUrl);
                }

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            browser.reload();
        }

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            browser.onPause();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            browser.onDestroy();
        }

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            browser.onResume();
        }

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public void onDownloadRequested(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
            if (!hasPermissionToDownload(getActivity())) return;

            String filename = null;
            try {
                filename = new GetFileInfo().execute(url).get();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (filename == null) {
                String fileExtenstion = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url);
                filename = URLUtil.guessFileName(url, null, fileExtenstion);
            }


            if (AdvancedWebView.handleDownload(getActivity(), url, filename)) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.download_done), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                onDownloadInterstitialAd();

            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.download_fail), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        private static boolean hasPermissionToDownload(final Activity context) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M ||
                    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED )
                return true;

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder.setMessage(R.string.download_permission_explaination);
            builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.common_permission_grant, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // Fire off an async request to actually get the permission
                    // This will show the standard permission request dialog UI
                    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                        context.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},1);
                }
            });
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            if (firstLoad == 0 && MainActivity.getCollapsingActionBar()){
                ((MainActivity) getActivity()).showToolbar(this);
                firstLoad = 1;
            } else if (firstLoad == 0){
                firstLoad = 1;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Show an interstitial ad
         */
        private void onDownloadInterstitialAd(){
            final InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(getActivity());
            mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.ad_interstitial_id));
            AdRequest adRequestInter = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build();
            mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAdLoaded() {
                    mInterstitialAd.show();
                }
            });
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequestInter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(String url) {
            //showInterstitial();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageError(int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onExternalPageRequest(String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            browser.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
```

And this is my Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DrawerFragment.DrawerFragmentListener{

    //Views
    public Toolbar mToolbar;
    public View mHeaderView;
    public TabLayout mSlidingTabLayout;
    public SwipeableViewPager mViewPager;

    //App Navigation Structure
    private NavigationAdapter mAdapter;
    private DrawerFragment drawerFragment;

    private WebFragment CurrentAnimatingFragment = null;
    private int CurrentAnimation = 0;

    //Identify toolbar state
    private static int NO = 0;
    private static int HIDING = 1;
    private static int SHOWING = 2;

    //Keep track of the interstitials we show
    private int interstitialCount = 0;

    SharedPreferences prefs;

    public FirebaseAuth authtt;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        authtt = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        mHeaderView = (View) findViewById(R.id.header_container);
        mSlidingTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        mViewPager = (SwipeableViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

        mAdapter = new NavigationAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), this);

        final Intent intent = getIntent();
        final String action = intent.getAction();

        if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(action)) {
            String data = intent.getDataString();
            ((App) getApplication()).setPushUrl(data);
        }

        hasPermissionToDo(this, Config.PERMISSIONS_REQUIRED);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) mViewPager.getLayoutParams();
        if ((Config.HIDE_ACTIONBAR && getHideTabs()) || ((Config.HIDE_ACTIONBAR || getHideTabs()) && getCollapsingActionBar())){
            lp.topMargin = 0;
        } else if ((Config.HIDE_ACTIONBAR || getHideTabs()) || (!Config.HIDE_ACTIONBAR && !getHideTabs() && getCollapsingActionBar())){
            lp.topMargin = getActionBarHeight();
        } else if (!Config.HIDE_ACTIONBAR && !getHideTabs()){
            lp.topMargin = getActionBarHeight() * 2;
        }

        if (Config.USE_DRAWER) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);

            drawerFragment = (DrawerFragment)
                    getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
            drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), mToolbar);
            drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);
        } else {
            ((DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)).setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
        }

        mViewPager.setLayoutParams(lp);

        mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(mViewPager.getAdapter().getCount() - 1);

        mSlidingTabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.accent));
        mSlidingTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
        mSlidingTabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                if (getCollapsingActionBar()) {
                    showToolbar(getFragment());
                }
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                showInterstitial();
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });

        for (int i = 0; i < mSlidingTabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
            if (Config.ICONS.length > i  && Config.ICONS[i] != 0) {
                mSlidingTabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(Config.ICONS[i]);
            }
        }

        // admob
        if (!getResources().getString(R.string.ad_banner_id).equals("")) {
            // Look up the AdView as a resource and load a request.
            AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        } else {
            AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
            adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }



        // application rating
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle(getString(R.string.rate_title))
                .setMessage(String.format(getString(R.string.rate_message), getString(R.string.app_name)))
                .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.rate_yes), null)
                .setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.rate_never), null)
                .setNeutralButton(getString(R.string.rate_later), null);

        new AppRate(this)
                .setShowIfAppHasCrashed(false)
                .setMinDaysUntilPrompt(2)
                .setMinLaunchesUntilPrompt(2)
                .setCustomDialog(builder)
                .init();

        // showing the splash screen
        if (Config.SPLASH) {
            findViewById(R.id.imageLoading1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //getFragment().browser.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    // using the back button of the device
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        View customView = null;
        WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback customViewCallback = null;
        if (getFragment().chromeClient != null) {
            customView = getFragment().chromeClient.getCustomView();
            customViewCallback = getFragment().chromeClient.getCustomViewCallback();
        }

        if ((customView == null)
                && getFragment().browser.canGoBack()) {
            getFragment().browser.goBack();
        } else if (customView != null
                && customViewCallback != null) {
            customViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {

        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        if (mAdapter != null && mAdapter.getCount() == 1 && !Config.USE_DRAWER && !Config.STATIC_TOOLBAR_TITLE)
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }

    public WebFragment getFragment(){
        return (WebFragment) mAdapter.getCurrentFragment();
    }

    boolean getHideTabs(){
        if (mAdapter.getCount() == 1 || Config.USE_DRAWER){
            return true;
        } else {
            return Config.HIDE_TABS;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {
        String url = Config.URLS[position];
        if (WebToAppWebClient.urlShouldOpenExternally(url)){
            try {
                view.getContext().startActivity(
                        new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
            } catch(ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                if (url.startsWith("intent://")) {
                    view.getContext().startActivity(
                            new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url.replace("intent://", "http://"))));
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, getResources().getString(R.string.no_app_message), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            getFragment().browser.loadUrl("about:blank");
            getFragment().setBaseUrl(Config.URLS[position]);
            showInterstitial();
            return true;
        }
    }

    private static boolean hasPermissionToDo(final Activity context, final String[] permissions) {
        boolean oneDenied = false;
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M &&
                    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission)
                            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                oneDenied = true;
        }

        if (!oneDenied) return true;

        android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setMessage(R.string.common_permission_explaination);
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.common_permission_grant, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // Fire off an async request to actually get the permission
                // This will show the standard permission request dialog UI
                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                    context.requestPermissions(permissions,1);
            }
        });
        android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        dialog.show();

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You create an InterstitialAd object but do not add it to any layouts(ViewGroup). That's why you can not see it, I think.

Comment: @mark-shen I can see that Ad but it isn't clickable. logcat says this => I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null. When i click on it

Comment: how did you solved the problem?